# Can I use windows inside a docker container?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2016, containers

I'm wondering, is it possible to configure a docker container to run Windows and then connect to it via RDP or parsec and use it as my main machine?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to configure a docker container to run Windows

Yes, you can [Run native Windows Server Containers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server)

> connect to it via RDP

Nope.

According to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35910354/213269), Windows Containers does not support RDP. To quote an article from 2019:

> But notice you still cannot RDP into such Windows containers.

See [What's new for Docker on Windows Server 2019?](https://stefanscherer.github.io/docker-on-windows-server-2019/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you can run containers with Windows. Microsoft even provides [official container images](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore), but don't expect them to be as versatile as Linux images. I don't have any experience with them because I didn't have any use for it yet.
From what I gathered you need a Windows host to run the containers, they don't run on Linux hosts (please correct me if I'm wrong here). You won't have a desktop either. If you manage to rdp into it (which I doubt is possible) you will get a command shell at most.
The containers are meant to run powershell scripts or applications without gui, nothing more.